# How is C's free used?

Tags: c, free

I am not sure when to call free? Can you help me with this?

Here is sample code:

```
char *array[1000];
for( i < 100){ //its example, it isnt correct syntax
        if(i%2 == 0){
           array[i] = someMethod(i);
        }else{
           array[i] = "BLABLABLA";
        }
}

char * someMethod(int i){
        char *pointer;
        pointer = malloc(i); // some lenght

.
.
.
.
.

       return pointer;
}
```

And now, I want to use `free` and delete all heap-allocated memory, when I have finished using the memory to prevent memory leaks, How can i do this?

`free(array);` doesn't work, reporting

> attempt to free non-heap object

Comment: `free` what you `malloc` - here each item in array, not array itself.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<100;i+=2)free(array[i]);`

Comment: It would be a good idea to refactor your code so you only have dynamically allocated memory in one place. Alternatively copy your string into dynamically allocated memory. That way subsequent operations on the array can be consistant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call free for each of the elements of `array`. `array` is a static array(which is also the error you get `attempt to free non-heap object`) and that is why you can not `free` it. It's elements on the other hand are dynamically allocated and you can and **should** free them. Write a simple cycle and call free for the elements of `array` in it.

EDIT: actually you can call free only on the dynamically allocated elements of `array`. As you assign string literals to some of the elements and allocated memory dynamically for others(using malloc), you will have to use a helper array where you store a flag for each element that indicates if it is dynamically allocated or points to a string literal. After that only free the dynamically allocated elements in a cycle.

Comment: The cycle won't be all that simple.  Some elements point to dynamically allocated memory but others point to string literals.

Comment: @simonc ouch I did not notice that. You are right. Cycle will still be simple, but we will need to take care to track which are dynamically allocated elements somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You can (really should) have exactly one call to `free` for each call to `malloc`.

```
array[i] = someMethod(i);
```

should therefore be (later) paired with

```
free(array[i]);
```

This won't work however because

```
array[i] = "BLABLABLA";
```

assigns some elements to point to string literals.  You didn't allocate memory for these so can't `free` them.

You'll need to either remember which elements were dynamically allocated or allocate memory for the elements that currently contain literals

```
array[i] = strdup("BLABLABLA");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to free all the elements.

```
for( i < 100){
 if(i%2 == 0)
   free(array[i]);
 i++;
}
```

But in this way, the whole array will not be freed. as you have assigned string literals to some of them, that can not be freed.
You can only `free` memories that are dynamically allocated like using `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: Calling `free` on a string literal will not leak memory.  It'll probably crash but this isn't guaranteed.

Comment: calling free will not cause leak, but if array[i] = malloc (some size) and array[i] ="afdsfaf" is executed in sequence, `malloc`ed address is lost, so there will be a leak.

Comment: True but that isn't the pattern shown in the question.  Each element there is assigned once only - to either dynamically allocated memory or a string literal.  I don't see any code that overwrites assigned elements.

Comment: opps! overlooked that.